# Combining 3 Timestamp into one timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## I want to combine 3 diferent timestamp into one column of timestamp

I have 3 different column that log the time the job is created, rejected and completed. i want to combine it all into one Timestamp column.

This is an example data that i have

| ID | j_date_created | j_date_completed | j_date_rejected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23.03.2021 07:34:34 | 23.03.2021 07:34:36 | null |
| 2 | 23.03.2021 07:34:34 | 23.03.2021 07:34:37 | null |
| 3 | 23.03.2021 07:34:34 | null | 04.04.2021 17:48:06 |

the end goal that i want is

| ID | timestamp | Activity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23.03.2021 07:34:34 | created |
| 1 | 23.03.2021 07:34:36 | completed |
| 2 | 23.03.2021 07:34:34 | created |
| 2 | 23.03.2021 07:34:37 | completed |
| 3 | 23.03.2021 07:34:34 | created |
| 3 | 04.04.2021 17:48:06 | rejected |

I am writing the project with pandas

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After renaming the columns, you can get the output you need using [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3],
                   'j_date_created': ['23.03.2021 07:34:34', '23.03.2021 07:34:34', '23.03.2021 07:34:34'],
                   'j_date_completed': ['23.03.2021 07:34:36', '23.03.2021 07:34:37', np.NaN],
                   'j_date_rejected': [np.NaN, np.NaN, '04.04.2021 17:48:06']})

df.columns = ['ID', 'created', 'completed', 'rejected']

df2 = df.melt(id_vars=['ID'], value_vars=['created', 'completed', 'rejected']).dropna().sort_values(by='ID')
df2.columns = ['ID', 'Activity', 'Timestamp']
print(df2)
```

This stacks the timestamp values in the `created`, `completed`, and `rejected` columns  and makes a new column with those old column names as values. It also drops rows with missing values in that column, then sorts by the `ID` column to get the correct grouping. Last is renaming the columns to replace the default column names provided by `melt`.

Output:

```
   ID   Activity            Timestamp
0   1    created  23.03.2021 07:34:34
3   1  completed  23.03.2021 07:34:36
1   2    created  23.03.2021 07:34:34
4   2  completed  23.03.2021 07:34:37
2   3    created  23.03.2021 07:34:34
8   3   rejected  04.04.2021 17:48:06
```